# Google Guice, Google Gin and Spring

Tags: spring, gwt, guice, gwt-gin

I am planning to improve an already written code, which is a GWT application and needs to be deployed on GAE.

The dependency Injection is taken care by Guice and Gin. I am wondering if I can use Spring at the back end.(which is kind of a strict requirement).

I have the client code working properly and sending requests to my server code, In the `Service' class which lies in the Server code, I want to do a Spring injection for DAO layer.

But unfortunately the DAO reference is null even if I do a `@Autowired` injection. This results in a NPE.

I am aware that you can only inject pring managed beans within a spring context. So I tried putting an annotation @Service on the server side class which is receiving the RPC request from the client code. The class looks something like below:

```
@Path(ResourcesPath.PERSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Service
public class PersonResource {

private Logger logger;

@Autowired
PersonDAO dao;

@Inject
PersonResource(Logger logger) {
    this.logger = logger;
}
}
```

I am hoping for something like this

```
@Path(ResourcesPath.PERSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class PersonResource {

private Logger logger;

@Inject
PersonResource(Logger logger) {
    this.logger = logger;
}
}
```

Thank you for your help. Please suggest me something which can solve this.

Answer (score 1):

To use the @Service annotation with your config spring you must configure your context like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>

</beans>
```

Spring will scan the package to found component annotations.

If you use java 5+, you can use the java configuration like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"org.example"})
public class ExampleConfig {

....
}
```

See the doc [Classpath scanning and managed components](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by configuring the Spring context as mentioned above or explained in [this nice tutorial](http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/07/29/gwt-rpc-integration-with-spring/).

Many libraries can help you integrate GWT RPC mechanism with Spring, 
i.e [gwtrpc-spring](https://code.google.com/p/gwtrpc-spring/) or [spring4gwt](https://code.google.com/p/spring4gwt/)

Many more example can be found on the web.